# Errors installing rosdep

Tags: ros, rosdep, rosdep-install, osx, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the rosdep installation/setup instructions as given on the ROS website for OSX/Homebrew, and having run step 2.1.2 (Resolving Dependencies) I get the following errors, in a process that otherwise appears to succeed:

```
ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: "geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_kdl-0.3.5 is not a subdirectory with contents in members ['geometry-experimental-release-release-tf2_kdl-0.3.5']"[/vcstools]
ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: "geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_tools-0.3.5 is not a subdirectory with contents in members ['geometry-experimental-release-release-tf2_tools-0.3.5']"[/vcstools]
ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: "geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_geometry_msgs-0.3.5 is not a subdirectory with contents in members ['geometry-experimental-release-release-tf2_geometry_msgs-0.3.5']"[/vcstools]
ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: "geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_ros-0.3.5 is not a subdirectory with contents in members ['geometry-experimental-release-release-tf2_ros-0.3.5']"[/vcstools]
ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: "geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_msgs-0.3.5 is not a subdirectory with contents in members ['geometry-experimental-release-release-tf2_msgs-0.3.5']"[/vcstools]
ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: "geometry_experimental-release-release-geometry_experimental-0.3.5 is not a subdirectory with contents in members ['geometry-experimental-release-release-geometry_experimental-0.3.5']"[/vcstools]
[rosconsole] Done.
ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: "geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2-0.3.5 is not a subdirectory with contents in members ['geometry-experimental-release-release-tf2-0.3.5']"[/vcstools]

...

[kdl] Done.
[gencpp] Done.
[vision_opencv] Done.
[dynamic_reconfigure] Done.
[ivcon] Done.
[orocos_kdl] Done.
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'tf2_geometry_msgs' : [tf2_geometry_msgs] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2_geometry_msgs/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_geometry_msgs-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2_geometry_msgs failed.
Error processing 'tf2_kdl' : [tf2_kdl] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2_kdl/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_kdl-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2_kdl failed.
Error processing 'tf2_ros' : [tf2_ros] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2_ros/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_ros-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2_ros failed.
Error processing 'geometry_experimental' : [geometry_experimental] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/geometry_experimental/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-geometry_experimental-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometry_experimental failed.
Error processing 'tf2_tools' : [tf2_tools] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2_tools/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_tools-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2_tools failed.
Error processing 'tf2_msgs' : [tf2_msgs] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2_msgs/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_msgs-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2_msgs failed.
Error processing 'tf2' : [tf2] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2 failed.

ERROR in config: Error processing 'tf2_geometry_msgs' : [tf2_geometry_msgs] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2_geometry_msgs/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_geometry_msgs-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2_geometry_msgs failed.
Error processing 'tf2_kdl' : [tf2_kdl] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2_kdl/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_kdl-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2_kdl failed.
Error processing 'tf2_ros' : [tf2_ros] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2_ros/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_ros-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2_ros failed.
Error processing 'geometry_experimental' : [geometry_experimental] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/geometry_experimental/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-geometry_experimental-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometry_experimental failed.
Error processing 'tf2_tools' : [tf2_tools] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2_tools/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_tools-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2_tools failed.
Error processing 'tf2_msgs' : [tf2_msgs] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2_msgs/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2_msgs-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2_msgs failed.
Error processing 'tf2' : [tf2] Checkout of https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry-experimental-release/archive/release/tf2/0.3.5.tar.gz version geometry_experimental-release-release-tf2-0.3.5 into /Users/alex/ros_catkin_ws/src/tf2 failed.
```

They all seem to concern 'tf2', whatever that is.

Does anyone have an idea what's going here? I'm installing on OS X 10.8.2, with a brew version of Python, in case it's relevant.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55363/errors-installing-rosdep/) by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-15**:
Instructions at <www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source>, FYI. It seems I can actually post links in comments.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-15**:
And here are the errors: https://gist.github.com/alexreg/4965426

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-16**:
@kalectro: What does "made it into the generator" mean? Anyway the error still occurs. I'd like to figure out what's going on, although I will take your `rm` suggestion for now, thanks.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-16**:
Step 2.1.1 will download all sources produced by a generator. If you want to know which source are being produced, open the link in a browser http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop
Did the rm suggestion work or not?

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-16**:
I'm still not sure what a "generator" (maybe it's like a distribution type) is but alright, cheers! Trying to install with your rm suggestion now. The next step is constantly failing each time I retry, because it reports a certain package is missing usually.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-17**:
@kalectro: Do you think we could debug this issue anyway? I'm quite curious why it's not working.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-18**:
@kalectro: So I've actually noticed other errors in the log now, shortly before the ones I posted previously. I've updated the Gist so you can see -- basically the problem is that bad assumptions are being made about the directory structure of the tarballs for some of the tf2 stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like tf2 made it into the generator, that is new. I do not know why you were not able to pull it but you can safely remove it from your src folder because you will most likely not use it.

```
rm -rf src/tf2*
```

Maybe it will also work if you just try again, the last commit was 8 hours ago.

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem and I found that the name of the folder where the geometry_experimental packages untars has changed to geometry2. For example:

```
geometry_experimental-release-release-indigo-tf2-0.5.11-0 --> geometry2-release-release-indigo-tf2-0.5.11-0
```

You will need to edit you rosintall file so wstool can find the folder.

For example if you had the following in your rosintall file:

```
- tar:
    local-name: geometry_experimental/tf2
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry_experimental-release/archive/release/indigo/tf2/0.5.11-0.tar.gz
    version: geometry_experimental-release-release-indigo-tf2-0.5.11-0
```

would need to change into this:

```
- tar:
    local-name: geometry_experimental/tf2
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/geometry_experimental-release/archive/release/indigo/tf2/0.5.11-0.tar.gz
    version: geometry2-release-release-indigo-tf2-0.5.11-0
```

---

Originally posted by [Ernesto Corbellini](https://answers.ros.org/users/23887/ernesto-corbellini/) with karma: 101 on 2016-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1